# Creating an index for ms sql server 2000 table using Oracle sql developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create the following index for a Ms SQL server 2000 table using Oracle sql developer version 4.0.2 ,

```
Create Nonclustered Index [Load_Date] On <table_name>
(   [Load_Date] Asc )
With ( Pad_Index = Off, Statistics_Norecompute = Off, Sort_In_Tempdb =Off, Drop_Existing=Off,Online = Off, Allow_Row_Locks = On,Allow_Page_Locks = On )
On Primary
```

I am getting two errors ,

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
```

And

```
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: Line 3: Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ? I need to create the index across multiple databases.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the syntax for the index. The mentioned syntax will work on SQL Server 2012. The syntax should be changed for MS SQL Server 2000.